# Development of an audio player. How to stop updating seekbar notification (Mediastyle) when manipulating it by the user

Tags: android, notifications, seekbar

I'm developing an audio player, creating a Notification in Mediastyle style, with play, pause and seekbar buttons. The seekbar is updated once every half a second, taking the value from the current position of the media player. And everything works fine until the user independently starts rewinding the seekbar.

When the user moves the slider, a callback is triggered:

```
MediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int)position);
        }
```

But due to the fact that the seekbar is updated every half a second, the user cannot move the seekbar slider indefinitely.
Question: How can I stop updating the seekbar reading while it is being manipulated by the user. I know that seekbar has callbacks:

```
private boolean isTouch;
public void setSeekbar(SeekBar seekBarPlayer) {
    seekBarPlayer.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isTouch = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isTouch = false;
        }
    });
}
```

But I can't intercept them since I don't have a reference to the current seekbar to override the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it

```
mediaSession.setPlaybackState(
    PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
        .setState(
            PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING,
                        
            // Playback position.
            // Used to update the elapsed time and the progress bar. 
            mediaPlayer.currentPosition.toLong(), 
                        
            // Playback speed. 
            // Determines the rate at which the elapsed time changes. 
            playbackSpeed
        )

        // isSeekable. 
        // Adding the SEEK_TO action indicates that seeking is supported 
        // and makes the seekbar position marker draggable. If this is not 
        // supplied seek will be disabled but progress will still be shown.
        .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO)
        .build()
)
```